# WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns SYSTEM when ran from custom action

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, windows-authentication

I have an install project (running on Windows 7) that launches a custom action at commit which starts the application that was just installed.  During the startup of this application I have a method that checks the current user's name to perform some authentication.  When launched from this custom action I am getting 'NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM' instead of 'DOMAIN\USER'

**Update:**
This link from the accepted answer is what solved my issue:

[How can I customize an MSI in the Visual Studio setup/deployment project?](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should read the value of the [`USERNAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372385%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSI property:

```
string username = Session.Property("USERNAME");
```

The above will work in immediate execution mode; however, in deferred mode you will explicitly have to pass the user name using the `CustomActionData` property to your custom action. For details see here:

> [Tip: MSI Properties and Deferred
>   Execution](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/PDF/CustomActionData.pdf)

**UPDATE:** If you want to launch the installed application after the setup is completed you might prefer the approach described in this article:

> [Launching Your Application After Install using Visual Studio 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx)

or use Aaron Stebner's script to modify your MSI:

> **[How can I customize an MSI in the Visual Studio setup/deployment project?](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx)**

Comment: The code where the call to 'WindowsIdentity' is located in the application that is being installed, it has no knowledge of the msi

Comment: @jwarzech: Then your question seems to be a different one? "How to launch the installed application after installation?" Which tool do you use to produce your setup?

Comment: I have a VS2008 deployment project that installs an application and then calls a CustomAction that runs 'Process.Start(myapplication)'.  The first thing that the application does is checks the WindowsIdentity and looks up the user in an authorization database table.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is what I used in my Installer class as Custom Actions. This will return the current logged in user and not 'NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

```
    IdentityReference identity = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN") + "\\" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"))
```